# How to create function with Return Type as (TABLE student_name string)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am creating function using pgAdmin4 and the CODE Basically something like

```
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
    SELECT * FROM teest."students";
END
```

I am just wondering, how do I set the TABLE ReturnType as
`TABLE(applicant_id integer, ship_id integer)` something like that. There's no TABLE return type there.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Either by using [`returns table`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-TABLE)

```
create function get_students()
 returns table(applicant_id integer, ship_id integer)
as
$$
  select applicant_id, ship_id
  from test.students
$$
language sql;
```

```
create function get_student_names()
 returns table(student_name text)
as
$$
  select name
  from test.students
$$
language sql;
```

Or by using [`setof`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET)

```
create function get_students
 returns setof students
as
$$
  select *
  from test.students
$$
language sql;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry for saying this but I am actually using pgAdmin4 to create the function, I tried to put the code you gave me under "CODE" but apparently its not working.

Comment: Those are simple SQL statements, just run them. I don't use pgAdmin, but there must be a way to execute SQL statements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, but I need to do it using pgAdmin4, the team I am working with proposes that

Comment: I am sure pgAdmin can run those SQL statements.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I cannot select `setof` or `table()` as a return type from the GUI in pgAdmin. I am sure I could create the code from scratch, but it feels like I must be missing something.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Create Function option from the pgAdmin menu, you can select a basic option (I usually use "text"). Make sure that you also go to the options tab and set "Returns a Set?" to yes. Then, once you have saved your code, click Save.

Next, go to the sidebar where your function has been added and right-click "Scripts > CREATE Script" and you should see something that looks like this:

```
-- FUNCTION: public.function_name()

-- DROP FUNCTION public.function_name();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.function_name(
    )
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 5

AS $BODY$

BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
    SELECT * FROM teest."students";
END

$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.function_name()
    OWNER TO owner_name;
```

Remove the two hyphens in Line 3 and then update the RETURNS statement in Line 7 with

`RETURNS TABLE(columnname1 columntype1, columnname2, columntype2, ...)`

You should execute your query like this and it will delete the old query. Then make sure to restore the two hyphens in line 3 and execute again.

Then, when you open a query editor and execute

`SELECT * FROM function_name()`

you should get your table output as you intended.